# Calling php from php through exec()

Tags: php, websocket

**How to execute the following code from a php file not from shell**

exec("php -q /home/abc/public_html/chat/server.php");

ps i want to mention that script is running if i type it in shell but i want to execute if from php.

Comment: Use `include` or `require` within the page being accessed.

Comment: What about this does not work? Errors? Logs? Something? Voting to close for lack of details. Please [edit] your question to add more information as to what your problem actually is here.

Comment: `exec` uses the shell. So, if the command works in the `shell` but not in `php exec` then the environment must be different. Check paths and environment variables and the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to require the file like this to execute it's contents from another php-file

```
<?php
    require_once("/home/abc/public_html/chat/server.php");
?>
```

**OR** if you are referring to supressing all output in the required script you could try supressing it with ob_start():

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    require_once("/home/abc/public_html/chat/server.php");
    ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Comment: i want to make a websocket server and to work first i must to run this file from shell although is not working

Comment: I am not quite sure if I follow you. You state that you want to execute the code from another php-file and not shell? "How to execute the following code from a php file"

Comment: yes from another php file but it must to be equivalent with shell.Normally i must to execute it from shell but i want to make a php script and this script to execute this shell command

Comment: So you are referring to the -q flag? Supressing HTTP header output? Which headers do you not want to send?

Comment: if you type what is inside of exec function in shell it will open a process in linux i want to open it from php not from shell

Comment: Yes so if you wan't to execute the content of server.php without running exec() you just run require_once() as seen in my answer

Comment: i want to run it from exec() but is not working from exec().And i don't know why is not working that's the question